# How to disable (prevent) the mobile web site from horizontal swipe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

I'm using following meta tags. But as you can see in the pictures from the emulator, my website swipes with all the content in it.(Img 1 is the normal case which it supposed to look like and img 2 is the version that i'm trying to resolve.) I'm using small grids in it. I have this problem only on Android devices.

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

[image][image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having an overflowing issue, your one of the DIVs are going beyond the screen.
Check your HTML code and find out your culprit DIV. Set DIV width to 100%. I would have changed my HTML code a bit rather than using hack to prevent swiping, and hence horizontal scroll bar to appear.

Comment: Yeah that was the case. So I ended up giving overflow-x:hidden to the overflowed div. Thanks:D